# Is it completely safe to mix an AMD processor with a Nvidia GPU?

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, compatibility, amd-ryzen

I trying to understand if an AMD Ryzen 7 2700X processor could be suitable
for an RTX 2070 or a GTX 1080Ti, and vice versa. 
Is it OK to build a PC having these two components on the same motherboard?

Comment: He isnt asking for hardware shopping recommendations.  He is asking if two different brands will work with each other.

Comment: It would be useful to know what your specific concern is. What motivates you to be concerned this might not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely, there is no problem to mix AMD processor with Nvidia GPU.

You can simply search on Amazon or any other marketplace online to see built configuration with AMD and Nvidia. Eg : [https://www.amazon.com/SkyTech-ArchAngel-Gaming-Computer-Quad-Core/dp/B077QDM2DP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B077QDM2DP)